# Как расположить текст справа от картинки в две строки

Tags: html, css

У меня есть два варианта

1- Используя сетку bootstrap

```
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                  <img src="img/icon-med.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                  Медный прокат
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            ....
          </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все работает, но что-то мне подсказывает, что так не нужно делать

2- вариант, который я нашел на просторах StackOverflow

```
    <div class="col-md-2" style="position: relative;">
      <img src="img/icon-alumin.png" style="position: absolute;top:0px;left:0px;">
      <p style="margin-left: 57px;">Алюминиевый прокат</p>
    </div>
```

Вроде бы все работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, при уменьшении разрешения, они начинают друг на друга залазить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем вопрос, как это все правильно реализовать? Просто использовать сетку bootstrap или колдовать дальше со 2 вариантом?

Comment: первый вариант с бутстрапом вполне приемлемый. можно не использовать col и row, достаточно вместо row указать d-flex (bootstrap v.4), эффект будет идентичным. второй вариант тоже в определенных случаях приемлем, но ясное дело что второй вариант не адаптивный. я бы советовал использовать бутстрап - у него очень очень большой функционал - почти для любой задачи подойдет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.block{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.block__pict > img{
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
}
.block__caption{
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="block__pict">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div class="block__caption">
        Алюминиевый прокат
    </div>
</div>
```